# Can we disable two finger scroll in Mac/book,using javaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, css, trackpad

Hello  i have a situation , I have a div container with a width of 300px and position relative and overflow hidden ,and i have two other child div inside it with position absolute, i'm translating them using css3  -transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)  then on click transform: translate3d(-400px, 0, 0); vice  versa ,its working fine on windows but on Mac/macbook system while using two finger scroll the div container is overflowing and able to see the transmitted div(sometime white empty space)

Comment: Are you sure it's only when scrolling from two fingers? Seems odd. IMHO it's more likely that mac system does set the focus on hovered element for scrolling, so it should happen even with a mouse or on any system if you set the focus to this element. btw, could you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can try?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. There is no two finger scroll on MAC, is just scroll (two finger is the way that use a MAC to interact with the hardware).

If you want to **prevent scrolling** on MAC you need to **identify** if is a MAC computer and then **set overflow hidden** for your `div` or do what you need to do.

You could do something like this:

```
var isMac = navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC')>=0;

if (isMac) {
  document.getElementById('container').style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
```